# Angular code deployment to Azure failed - reason: read ECONNRESET

Tags: angular, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to deploy my code from Visual Studio Code (1.66.0) to Azure WebAPP. Code is getting built successfully but when I am trying to deploy getting below error.

> Error: request to https://igim-admin.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy?isAsync=true&author=VS%20 Code failed, reason: read ECONNRESET

Answer (score 1):

Solution - Downgrade my Visual Studio Version to 1.64 from 1.66 and successfully deployed.

Comment: Thanks @Bhuwan you saved me a long night of research.